# C++ : Exception occurred in script: basic_string::_S_construct NULL not valid

Tags: c++, linux

I am returning a string or NULL from the database function to the main program, sometimes i get this error from the exception:

```
basic_string::_S_construct NULL not valid
```

i think its because of the return NULL value from the database function? any ideas???

```
string database(string& ip, string& agent){
  //this is just for explanation
  .....
  ....

  return NULL or return string

}

int main(){
   string ip,host,proto,method,agent,request,newdec;
   httplog.open("/var/log/redirect/httplog.log", ios::app);

   try{
      ip = getenv("IP");
      host = getenv("CLIENT[host]");
      proto = getenv("HTTP_PROTO");
      method = getenv("HTTP_METHOD");
      agent = getenv("CLIENT[user-agent]");

      if (std::string::npos != host.find(string("dmnfmsdn.com")))
         return 0;

      if (std::string::npos != host.find(string("sdsdsds.com")))
         return 0;

      if (method=="POST")
         return 0;

      newdec = database(ip,agent);
      if (newdec.empty())
         return 0;
      else {
         httplog << "Redirecting to splash page for user IP: " << ip << endl;
         cout << newdec;
         cout.flush();
      }
      httplog.close();
      return 0; 
   }
   catch (exception& e){
      httplog << "Exception occurred in script: " << e.what() << endl;
      return 0;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You cannot return `NULL` (or `0`) from a function that is declared to return `string` because there is no appropriate implicit conversion. You might want to return an empty string though

```
return string();
```

or

```
return "";
```

If you want to be able to distinguish between a `NULL` value and an empty string, then you will have to use either pointers (smart ones, preferrably), or, alternatively, you could use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) (or [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) before C++17).

Comment: Just to clarify, there is an _available_ implicit conversion from `NULL` to `std::string` because `std::string` has a non-explicit constructor taking a `const char*` which `NULL` will convert to. The issue is that `NULL` is not an appropriate value to use with this constructor because it violates a precondition.

Comment: An implementation might be able to detect this error at compile time, but this is not required. The type of `NULL` isn't fully specified, but it can't be `const char*`. Therefore, the conversion to `const char*` may not be the best.

Answer (score 15):

It's a violation of `std::string`'s contract to construct it from a null `char` pointer. Just return an empty string if the pointer that you want to construct it from is null.

E.g.

```
return p == NULL ? std::string() : std::string(p);
```

Comment: I'd prefer `return std::string(p?p:"");` as that's a slightly simpler return expression which may help RVO.

Comment: @MSalters: I prefer not to construct empty strings from a `""` string literal. It seems wasteful but it's a silly hangup; it's just me.

Comment: Or even a bit shorter, the so called [elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator#C) `return std::string(d?:"");`

Answer (score 2):

I would try changing it to return an empty string instead of null and check the string length.