# Mex runtime error: Unexpected standard expression

Tags: c++, matlab, runtime, mex

I am new to Mex. After building a C++ Mex file, I get this error immediately at runtime.

```
>> [a b c] = read_svm('/All/testhalf_Anger_1.libsvm');
Unexpected Standard exception from MEX file.
What() is:basic_string::_S_construct NULL not valid
..
```

This is what the execution of my code looks like

Thank You in advance!

Comment: debug the mex file: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/debugging-c-c-language-mex-files.html

Comment: related question: [C++ : Exception occurred in script: basic\_string::\_S\_construct NULL not valid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052997/c-exception-occurred-in-script-basic-string-s-construct-null-not-valid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message explains it very well, somewhere in your code you're constructing a `basic_string` by passing a NULL pointer to its constructor. The `basic_string` constructor that takes a `CharT *` requires that the pointer be non-NULL, hence the crash.

Note that `std::string` and `std::wstring` are typedefs for the `std::basic_string` class template, so you may be using one of these in your code.

You can fix this by doing something similar to the following snippet

```
char const *p = nullptr;

// std::string s(p); // This is not allowed!
std::string s( p ? p : "" ); // string will be empty if p is NULL
```